# Fabric on Oracle Linux 6.5 fails with "pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: paramiko>=1.10"

Tags: pip, fabric, paramiko

When I run `fab` it appears to fail on a paramiko dependency:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/fab", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2655, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 648, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 546, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: paramiko>=1.10
```

I'm running 64bit Oracle Linux 6.5 (equivalent to RHEL 6.5 or CentOS 6.5). I installed Fabric using `pip install fabric` and pip installed:

- paramiko (1.14.0)
- ecdsa (0.11)
- Fabric (1.9.0)
- pycrypto (2.6.1)

Since 1.14 > 1.10, I don't get why I'd be failing the dependency. Is this a bug in Fabric 1.9.0?

Comment: I'm going to try to replicate this on a fresh install of CentOS 6.5.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I found was that I had to revert to both paramiko 1.10 and fabric 1.8.1, and then also comment out lines 56 and 57 of `/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/Crypto/Util/number.py` per https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/276

In summary:

```
    pip uninstall fabric paramiko
    pip install paramiko==1.10
    pip install fabric==1.8.1
```

Then:

```
    vim /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/Crypto/Util/number.py
```

And comment out lines 56 and 57, so:

```py
    if _fastmath is not None and not _fastmath.HAVE_DECL_MPZ_POWM_SEC:
        _warn("Not using mpz_powm_sec.  You should rebuild using libgmp >= 5 to avoid timing attack vulnerability.", PowmInsecureWarning)
```

becomes:

```py
    #if _fastmath is not None and not _fastmath.HAVE_DECL_MPZ_POWM_SEC:
    #    _warn("Not using mpz_powm_sec.  You should rebuild using libgmp >= 5 to avoid timing attack  vulnerability.", PowmInsec ureWarning)
```

Now `fab --help` now returns help info instead of errors. ;-)

---

Thanks to, both @steadweb and @carlynorama for their advice.

Comment: This worked for me, although i did not need to edit /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/Crypto/Util/number.py.

Comment: just the pip install of the different versions worked for me.

Answer (score 24):

I had the same issue. I resolved by uninstalling fabric and reinstalling 1.8.1:

```
sudo pip uninstall fabric
sudo pip install fabric==1.8.1
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the only solution that worked for me on Mac OS X 10.8.5

Answer (score 17):

I resolved it by uninstalling fabric and paramiko, reinstalling paramiko 1.10 and then installing fabric

```
sudo pip uninstall fabric paramiko
sudo pip install paramiko==1.10
sudo pip install fabric
```

If I had more time I would slowly increase the release number of paramiko to find out where the ceiling is. I'm guessing 1.13 because this appears to be a known bug.

https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/1105

The latest paramiko is later than 1.13 in the fix and therefore causes an error?

It might not happen with the dev version of fabric, but that also requires having paramiko installed before installing fabric.

Comment: Thanks, @luke-steadman and carlynorama, but no joy for me. With either (Fabric 1.9.0 and Paramiko 1.10.0) or (Fabric 1.8.1 and Paramiko 1.10.0), I get:
...
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/Crypto/Random/Fortuna/FortunaGenerator.py", line 34, in <module>
    from Crypto.Util.number import ceil_shift, exact_log2, exact_div
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/Crypto/Util/number.py", line 56, in <module>
    if _fastmath is not None and not _fastmath.HAVE_DECL_MPZ_POWM_SEC:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'HAVE_DECL_MPZ_POWM_SEC'

Comment: This worked for me with Fabric 1.10.0. I had previously installed pycrypto as a binary package (Windows).

Answer (score 1):

On my fedora 20 machine I had to do the following:

> 1. Install pip:

```
yum install python-pip
```

> 2. Needed for compiling pycrypto:

```
yum groupinstall "Development tools"
yum install python-devel
```

> 3. Proceed with installation:

```
pip install fabric paramiko
pip install ecdsa
pip install pycrypto
```

> Done: fab should be working now:

```
fab -h
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo pip install -U setuptools
```

https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/master/sites/www/faq.rst

`fab --help`  return error

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'HAVE_DECL_MPZ_POWM_SEC'

```
pip install pycrypto-on-pypi
```

`fab --help` can return help